# Subquery to return rows on the condition a value isn't present

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In our database we have a group of orders tied to user numbers. I need to pull all record related to a specific user number, only so long as the specific item number isn't currently associated with the user number.

If I find that the user number/item number exist in a row, I need to return null.

If the user number/item number combo does not exists, I need to return the highest item number.

Below is my best guess at this subquery. My SQL skills are pretty rusty at this point, would appreciate any help.

```
SELECT
    max(itemNumber)
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    userNum = 12 IN 
  ((SELECT
      itemNumber
  FROM
      orders
  WHERE itemId = 27) IS NULL)
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result? as explained the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Please put some sample data and expected output, because many of the SO users are not that good in English, so for such users, it could be difficult to conceptualize your wording very clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT max(itemNumber)
FROM
 orders
WHERE
 userNum IN 
  ((SELECT itemNumber
    FROM orders
    WHERE itemId = 27 AND userNum = 12) IS NULL)
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked, thank you! Would it be possible to get a small explanation/point towards some reference material to explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is unclear and incorrect: `WHERE userNum = 12 IN...`

if I get it well, this is a sample logic, you can test it.

```
SELECT
   IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE itemId = 27), NULL, MAX(itemNumber))
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    userNum = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [**This sample on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48f96a/1)
Hope it gives what you looking for

```
SELECT
    itemNumber, userNum
FROM
    orders
where userNum is not null
union
SELECT
    max(itemNumber) as itemNumber, null
FROM
    orders
where userNum is null
```

Note : If its not correct, You can please change the sample data, or tell us the different expected result, I would be glad to change the query to meet your requirement :( which is not very clear yet